# Necessity of default constructor for members

Tags: c++

I am confused by a compiler error I'm receiving with C++14. It concerns the necessity of a default constructor for member variables. In the code below, class A does not have a default constructor. class B has a member of type A that it move assigns. The compiler complains about the lack of default constructor for A, even though I'm not explicitly calling it anywhere. Is there some implicit call to the default constructor of A happening in the constructor of B that I'm missing? My understanding was that if you initialize the members of B in the constructor of B, then the default constructor is not necessary.

The code in main works fine when B is commented out. What is essentially the same thing in the constructor of B does not work.

Thank you,

```
#include <utility>                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

class A { 
public:
  A(int x) : _x{x} {}
  A(A &&other) : _x{other._x} {}
  A &operator=(A &&other) { _x = other._x; }
private:
  int _x; 
};

class B { 
public:
  B() {
    A a(2);
    _a = std::move(a);
  }
private:
  A _a; 
};

int main() {
  A b(1);
  A a = std::move(b);
  return 0;
}
```

```sh
~/move.cpp: In constructor ‘B::B()’:
~/move.cpp:17:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
   B() {
       ^
~/move.cpp:7:3: note: candidate: A::A(A&&)
   A(A &&other) : _x{other._x} {}
   ^
~/move.cpp:7:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
~/move.cpp:5:3: note: candidate: A::A(int)
   A(int x) : _x{x} {}
   ^
~/move.cpp:5:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: `B() : _a(2) {}` ?

Comment: `A a = std::move(b);` is initialization, `_a = std::move(a);` is assignation. `_a` is initialized in `B() : _a() {`.

Comment: That works, though I thought that _a(2) would invoke the move constructor rather than move assignment. The move constructor should be deleted b/c I declared move assignment and didn't declare move constructor.
Edit: I provided both, I'm guess what I'm wondering is why it's not ok to use move assignment to initialize rather than move constructor . For example, if someone provided move assignment, but their move constructor was malformed.

Comment: The following would call the assignment: `A b(1); A a(2); a = std::move(b);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some implicit call to the default constructor of A happening in the constructor of B that I'm missing?

Yes. From the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

> Before the compound statement that forms the function body of the constructor begins executing, initialization of all direct bases, virtual bases, and **non-static data members** is finished.

(emphasis mine)

So in the constructor

```
B()   {
 // ^ here
```

before the opening brace, the member `_a` is initialized. But since there's no default constructor, you get an error. You can avoid this by initializing it explicitly

```
B() : _a(42) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
B() { <- tries to call A(); 
B() : _a(2) <- calls A(int x); 
B() : _a(A(2)) <- Calls A(const A&) and A(int x)
B(A a) : _a(std::move(a)) <- calls A(A &&other)
```

Comment: Latter (might) calls `A(A&&)` (before C++17, since C++17, it is elided).

Comment: Please, add an explanation. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).